# Computing $P(x)$ from $P(x,y)$

Tags: probability, integration

Given the $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ following probability density function $P(x,y)$:

$$P(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1/8, & \text{if } x \in \left[ -1, 1 \right]^3 \text{ and } y = x_1 + 2x_2 + 2x_3 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

I would like to compute $P(y|x)$. In order to so, I was thinking about computing first $P(x)$ and then through the Bayes theorem to get to $P(y|x)$. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to compute $P(x)$ in this case.

May I ask your help?

Comment: This is a discrete problem. There are only $8$ outcomes so if you write the eight 4-tuples you can answer this by counting.

Comment: ahh damm, I wrote it wrong. I meant with x being a continuous variable. Not a discrete one

Comment: Either way, there are only a finite number of non-zero outcomes. You should be able to write $P(x)$ in cases as you did with $P(x,y)$.

Comment: How do you know that are only finite number of non-zero outcomes?

Comment: If $x$ is not one of the eight points listed then $P(x,y)=0$. Moreover, for each of the eight points listed, $y$ can only take on one value. Write out the non-zero points in $\mathbb R^4$ and you will see what I mean.

Comment: For instance, let's say y = 0 . now we x1 + 2x2 + 2x3 = 0. This equation already two independent linear combinations. we have y from -inf to +inf. How can you say that there are just eight points?

Comment: @John Douma I believe he means $-1\le x_i\le 1$ for each $i$, not just the end points.

Comment: @herbsteinberg yeah, thank you

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thank you. I see. The original post said $x\in \{1,-1\}$ so I thought he meant the vertices of the cube.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of conditional probability (the abstract formulation involving sigma algebras and the Radon-Nikodym theorem)?

Comment: @JohnDouma yeah sorry about that, It was a typo

Comment: Rigorously speaking, $P(x, y)$ is not a (joint) p.d.f. because it is concentrated on a measure-zero subset of $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}$, i.e., it is degenerate. I guess this careless formulation of the problem is what confuses OP. Anyway, using common sense, the problem can be salvaged (without introducing measure-theoretic language) by realizing random variables $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3), Y$ such that $X\sim\operatorname{Uniform}([-1,1]^3)$ and $Y=X_1+2X_2+2X_3$.

Comment: @JackM I just know P(x|y ) = P(x,y)/(P(y))

Comment: @SangchulLee So you're saying that P(x,y) is really just a P(x) with a constraint? But in this way P(x|y) doesn't really make any sense to me.

Comment: The difficulty here is that the joint distribution is neither continuous nor discrete. And I guess you haven't been taught an appropriate language to describe this kind of situation. A rigorous formulation is that the joint distribution as probability measure $\mu$ is given by $$ \mu(dx, dy)=\frac{1}{8}\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]^3}(x)dx\,\delta_{x_1+2x_2+2x_3}(dy) $$ where $\delta_a$ is the Dirac delta concentrated at $a$. Its $x$-marginal can be computed by integrating this over $y$, which is simply $\frac{1}{8}\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(x)dx$, the uniform distribution over $[-1,1]^3$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Do you think is there a closed form solution or not?

Comment: If you are interested in the conditional distribution of $y$ given $x$, the answer is quite simple as you expected. $y$ is *completely* determined by $x$ by the formula $y=x_1+2x_2+2x_3$. So $$\mu(dy \mid x) = \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]^3}(x) \delta_{x_1+2x_2+2x_3}(dy),$$ or if we go back to the careless notation, $$P(y\mid x)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }y=x_1+2x_2+2x_3\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ If you are interested in the conditional distribution of $x$ given $y$, we need to compute some pesky triple integral (which computes volume of part of $[-1,1]^3$ divided by the plane $y=x_1+2x_2+2x_3$).